# Using the pseudo selector ::after

Tags: html, css

So i am placing 2 images side by side.

I am floating one left and the other right and i want clear the float with the pseudo selector ::after

The text underneath will just move in between the images.

I always have trouble with the ::after selector, it doesn't always work for me. Any pointers or advice would be appreciated.

EDIT: Forgot to add ::after code

CSS

```
div#product > img:first-child {
    float: left; 
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#product img {
    float: right; 
    margin-right: 55px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
img::after {
    clear:both;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="product">
            <img src="#" width="240" >
            <img src="#" width="240" >
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: just a heads up, its only one colon (:after) http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey [please don't use w3schools as a reference](http://w3fools.com/), one alternative is [MDN reference for the after selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/::after).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
img:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: It is definitely a single colon. What exactly isn't working? A jsFiddle would be helpful.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cUApv/3/ something like this works. Not 100% sure why the other way wasn't as I don't often use the technique.